# Search not working. Getting all results instead of specific results Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, model-view-controller

When I run my search posts in my Rails application, I get all of the posts existing in the database displayed instead of matched results.

Here is my controller method for search:

```
def search
    @posts=Post.find(:all, :conditions=>['text LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  end
```

The search.html.erb is:

```
<table class="table table-striped" summary="All posts">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Post #<%=post.id%>   </td>
        <td><%=post.text%></td>
        <%if post.image_file_name%>
        <td>
        <%=image_tag post.image.url %>
        </td>
        <%end%>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to("Like", {:action=>'#', :id=>post.id}, :class => 'action upvote')%></td>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
    </table>
```

Moreover, I have tried putting these in my model:

```
scope :search, lambda {|query|
        where (["text LIKE ?",  "%#{query}%"])
    }
def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, :conditions=>['text' 'LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end
```

but I get same results. Anyone can fix this? Thanks.

### UPDATE 1.0:

Here is the form for search which is located in `index.html.erb`:

```
<%=form_for(:post, :method=>'get', :url=>{:action=>'search', :html=> {:multipart=>true}}) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%=f.text_field(:text)%>
        <%=submit_tag("Search")%>
    </p>
  <%end%>
```

---

### UPDATE 1.1

Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mysql2','~> 0.3.11'
gem 'paperclip', '~>3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~>4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~>0.10.0' 
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: @muistooshort None of the search functions are working. But yes, I'm not getting an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

Comment: @muistooshort I have added the Gemfile in my question

Comment: @muistooshort jlhonora's answer is working in the IRB but it isn't behaving that way in the rails app. I think the search action is somehow not communicating with the search view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
def search
  criteria = params[:post][:search]
  @posts = Post.where('text LIKE ?', "%#{criteria}%")
end
```

For example:

```
> Post.where('text LIKE ?', '%SomeText%')
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (text LIKE '%SomeText%')
```

See [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), section 2.2

Comment: No change. Still getting all posts displayed.

Comment: If you do `puts "%#{params[:search]}%"` before the query, what do you get?

Comment: Just did `Post.where('text LIKE ?', '%SomeText%')` in rails c and its giving me the correct result in the IRB.

P.S where do I have to put `puts "%#{params[:search]}%"`?

Comment: @jlhonora: What would `f.text_field(:text)` end up putting into `params`?

Comment: @muistooshort
This what I get at the back-end
_Processing by PostsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "post"=>{"search"=>"Boot"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (text LIKE '%%')
  Rendered posts/search.html.erb within layouts/application (10.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 80ms (Views: 77.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)_

Comment: @jlhonora I get `%%` when do puts `"%#{params[:search]}%" before the query`

Comment: Then you should try with `params[:post][:search]`

Comment: @muistooshort depends on your full declaration of that line and `form_for` block. If you're not sure what you're getting then I'd recommend you to use `puts JSON.pretty_generate(params)` in your controller method.